# Admob. Не переходит на рекламируемый сайт

Tags: android, admob

Добавил в приложение межстраничную рекламу. Все отлично работает, реклама выводится где надо, но при клике на рекламу, активити рекламы просто закрывается. Т.е. не перекидывает на рекламируемый сайт. Уже не знаю куда копать, вроде как проблема не в коде, реклама то выводится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для каждого активити нужен свой рекламный блок.